# Can't find jedi-language-server in command line in mac but can in Linux

Tags: python, macos

## Questions

I install [jedi-language-server](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server) as the README.md. but I can't find `jedi-language-server --help` in My Mac(13 Ventura) system. But I can find this package in the `pip list`.

```bash
➜  ~ pip3 list | grep jedi
jedi                  0.18.2
jedi-language-server  0.40.0
```

### PATH and others

This is my new machine, not use `conda` or other `venv` moudle.

```bash
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/Users/vzgoll/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
➜  ~ which jedi-language-server
jedi-language-server not found
➜  ~ python3 -m site                
sys.path = [
    '/Users/vzgoll',
    '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
    '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
    '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/vzgoll/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages',
    '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/vzgoll/Library/Python/3.9' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/vzgoll/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

In order to verify, I install [jedi-language-server](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server) in my Arch Linux, It can use command `jedi-language-server --help`

So I want to ask why this happened.

## Solution

Add following code in my `~/.zshrc`.

```bash
pythonUserBaseDir=$(python3 -m site --user-base);
pythonUserBaseBinDir="$pythonUserBaseDir/bin"
export PATH="$pythonUserBaseBinDir:$PATH"
unset pythonUserBaseDir;
unset pythonUserBaseBinDir;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `$PATH` problem.

You didn't reveal anything about your `conda` or `venv`
config, and you didn't show us what `$ echo $PATH` says.
You should have a python project environment for
installing jedi and dependencies.
When you activate the environment, the relevant `/bin`
directory should be added to your `$PATH`.
Apparently that only happened properly on your Linux install.

Use `$ which jedi-language-server` and `$ ls -l` to
debug the details, so your Mac config resembles
the (working) Linux config.

Use `$ python -m site` to examine the
python library install directories.
Notice how its output changes when you
activate or deactivate the project environment.

EDIT

You're not using a project environment
for python library installs?
I don't recommend that.

There are very good reasons for using such
an environment, which the current question is highlighting.

Perhaps you used `sudo` when you pip installed it?
Where did the install go?
Use `ls -l` or `find` to locate it.
Verify that you have permission to read the
root-owned file.
Verify that you have added its directory
to your $PATH environment variable.

You have two OS environments, one of them working.
Use the tools mentioned above to find how
they differ, and to repair the faulty install.

Focus on that
/Users/vzgoll/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
directory.
You should see several recently installed libraries
in there, perhaps including jedi.
Sometimes a library will include a `bin` directory
under `site-packages`.
You should be able to run binaries by giving
the full path, or more conveniently by appending the `bin` directory
to your `$PATH` env var.

Comment: I don't know why I can't at you, I modify my question, please help me.

Comment: As you said, I find this problem. `jedi-language-server` in the `/Users/vzgoll/Library/Python/3.9/bin` so I add this path by myself.